# How to reload a div that has an include in it after submit, or even refresh the whole page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, page-refresh

sorry for the long explanation, but for the last 2 days I have been banging my head on this issue and have tried every which way to get my dynamic table or the page to refresh without having any success.  This issue comprises 3 pages, page one has includes that loads 3 different pages in Div's (these pages each have a table that loads a specific file list from a directory) the divs get have show/hide via the drop down also in every row I have a delete button which will delete the file in the aws bucket directory and remove that row from the table.

***The problem is when I click delete it will delete the file from the directory, but will not remove the row*** (*This works when on the actual page and not loaded into the div tags via the include*) if I refresh the page or click Delete a second time the row is then removed.  BTW the upload works flawlessly I have tride .location, jquery, javascript, ajax, tried stepping through the code in debug. I have put the ajax etc.. in the deletes3file.php before and after the echo also before and after each include and in each php file.  One thing I should mention is the deletes3file.php has an echo pop up so once I hit OK is when I want to remove the row from the table.

PAGE 1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/styles.css" /> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/panels.css"/>
```

```
    <body>
        <!-- Begin Wrapper -->
        <div id="wrapper">
         <!-- Begin Header -->
        <div id="header">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                    <a href="index.php">Home</a> 
                    <div class="cp-thumb">
                <div class="cp-hover">
                <?php
                  echo gethostname()
                ?>
            </div>
            </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            <div><a href="index.php" id="top-img"></a></div>
        </div>
    <!-- End Header -->

            <!-- Begin Content -->
        <div id="content">


<div id="dirlist">
<h2>Select Folder to upload to</h2>

<form action="uploads3.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1"
    <input type="hidden" name="method" value="post" />
      <select id="bucketName" name="bucketName">                 
        <option value="0">--Select Folder--</option>
        <option value="Policy">Policy</option>
        <option value="Program">Program</option>
        <option value="Procedures">Procedures</option>
     </select>
      <input name="theFile" type="file" />
      <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Upload">


    <script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('bucketName').addEventListener('change', function() {
     var style = this.value == "Policy" ? 'block' : 'none';
  document.getElementById('Policy').style.display = style;
     var style = this.value == "Program" ? 'block' : 'none';
  document.getElementById('Program').style.display = style;
     var style = this.value == "Procedures" ? 'block' : 'none';
  document.getElementById('Procedures').style.display = style;
});
</script>
</form>

</div><!-- End dirlist -->


<div id="Policy" style="display: none;">
<p><?php
include 'policy.php';
?></p>

</div>

<div id="Program" style="display: none;">
<p><?php
include 'program.php';
?></p>
</div>

<div id="Procedures" style="display: none;">
<p><?php
include 'procedures.php';
?></p>

</div>



     </div><!-- End Content -->
        </div><!-- End Wrapper -->


    </body>
</html>
```

DELETE PAGE:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['bucketName'])){
$bucketName = $_POST['bucketName']; 
}

$fname = $_POST['fname'];

include 'awss3con.php';
if($_POST){

if ($s3->deleteObject( $bucketName, $fname, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ)) {


                    echo "We successfully deleted your file $bucketName / $fname";

                }else{
                    echo "Something went wrong while delteing your file. $fname sorry.";
                }

    }

?>
```

THE PAGE IN THE INCLUDES:

```
<?php
$ignore = Array(".","..");
$count=1;
include 'awss3con.php';

// Get the contents of our bucket
echo '<form action="deletes3file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
 echo '<table id=db-table border=1>';
 echo '<th colspan=3 style="text-align:center;">Policies</th>';
  $contents = $s3->getBucket("MyBucket",'Policy');
    foreach ($contents as $file){
 //if(!in_array($file, $ignore));
  if(!isset($flag_first)){
    $flag_first=1;
     continue;
     }

        $fname = $file['name'];
        $furl = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/MyBucket/".$fname;
        $newname = explode('/', $fname);
        $fname = $newname['1'];
        $bucketName = "MyBucket/Policy";
        //output a link to the file
        /*echo "<tr id='del$count'><td>$count</td><td><input type='submit' name=$furl index=$count value='delete' onclick='deleteFile(\"$dispimage\",$count,\"$directory\");> <a href=\"$furl\">$fname</a>
        <input type='text' id=$count value=$furl name='furl' visible=''></td></tr>";*/
         echo "<tr id='del$count'><td>$count</td><td>$fname</td><td><input type='button' id='delete$count' value='Delete' onclick='deleteFile(\"$fname\",$count,\"$bucketName\");'></td></tr>";
        $count ++;

    }
    echo '</table>';
    echo "</form>";

        ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function deleteFile(fname,rowid,bucketName)
{
    $.ajax({ url: "deletes3file.php",
        data: {"fname":fname,"bucketName":bucketName},
        type: 'post',
        success: function(output) {
          alert(output);
          $("#del"+rowid).remove();
        }

    });

}
</script>
```

Comment: `window.location.reload();` will refresh the page, jQuery has [.remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Comment: You forgot the `>` in your opening tag `<form>`

Comment: Does `$("#del"+rowid).remove();` generate a javascript error?

Comment: Thanks Patrick,  i've tried that and no dice,  maybe I've placed it in the wrong place?  Where and what page would I put that in?

Comment: Hi James, $("#del"+rowid).remove(); does not result in and error...  i've tried putting the windows.location.reload(); after the success: function(output) but that doesn't work.  if I load the page separately not with the include everything works great.

Comment: `echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
echo 'alert("review your answer");'; 
echo 'window.location.href = "index.php";';
echo '</script>';`    Tried this in the deletes3file.php no dice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of attaching the event handler in HTML and passing parameters :

- Use HTML5 `data` attributes to associate data with HTML element(s).
- Attach event handlers in javascript.

This is better practice as it separates document structure from dynamic functionality, leading to better readbility of both HTML and javascript.

So, build rows as follows :

```
 echo "<tr data-fname=\"$fname\" data-bucket-name=\"$bucketName\"><td>$count</td><td>$fname</td><td><input class=\"deleteFile\" type=\"button\" value=\"Delete\"></td></tr>";
```

*Note: There's no need for any ids*

And write the corresponding script as follows :

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".deleteFile").on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // probably not necessary but won't do any harm.
        var $row = $(this).closest('tr'); // the clicked button's row.
        $.ajax({
            'url': 'deletes3file.php',
            'data': $row.data(), // the data object is composed for you automatically
            'type': 'post',
            'success': function(output) {
                $row.remove(); // here, you already have a reliable reference to the row that is to be deleted, so just remove() it.
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: Hi Roamer-1888,  Thanks! that works great except for one thing, it does not pass the bucketName or fname to the deletes3file.php file so it is not deleting from the S3 bucket it only removes it from the row.  Is there away to pass the bucketName.  The original script had data set to `data :{"fname":fname,"bucketName":bucketName},` your script has it as $row.data.  The deletes3file.php file is looking for the bucket and file name '<?php

if ($s3->deleteObject( $bucketName, $fname, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ)) {
'  
?>'

Comment: I should add it passes the $fname correctly, data: row.data should pass the variables in that row but only $fname is posting over to the deletes3file.php page the variable $bucketName passes null even though it is properly assigned a value in the table row.

Comment: Roamer-1888 thanks for the help,  i got it to work, looks like it passed $bucketName all in lower case (bucketname)  so in the deletes3file.php page i did this `$bucketName = $_POST['bucketname'];`

Comment: @tmac, my bad. Confusingly, data attributes need to be hyphen-separated in order to end up as camel case. Therefore `data-bucket-name=\"$bucketName\"` will come through to the PHP script as `$_POST['bucketName']`.